# When can I rely on onNext to be propagated synchronously?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

One of the core principles of [the Observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) is that all `onNext` notifications are emitted before an `onComplete`/`onError` notification. I'm wondering if I can ever rely on `onNext` notifications *from an operator* to always come before `onComplete` of the original `Observable`. There are obvious combination and timing operators like `delay`, `debounce` and `zip` where this cannot be true in general, but what about the likes of `map`, `scan` or `concat`?

This timing guarantee is important when retrying/repeating conditional on the stream items. For example, suppose I want to retry a streaming network request if a packet is dropped:

```js
const num_packets$ = new BehaviorSubject();
cold_request$.scan((num, _) => num + 1, 0)
  .repeatWhen(completions =>
    completions.takeWhile(_ => num_packets$.getValue() < expected_num_packets)
  )
  .subscribe(num_packets$);
```

The above code would be susceptible to a race condition between the last increment[s] of `num_packets$` and the completion of the request unless `onNext` notifications out of `scan` all come before the request stream completes.

Comment: Given that ["RxJS v5 ... defaults to having no scheduler at all,"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#default-scheduling-changed) I would posit that you can infer the guarantee you are seeking from the absence of a `Scheduler` parameter. That is, if the operator cannot be passed a `Scheduler`, it's always going to be synchronous propagation.

Comment: @concat Btw what output do you expect from the code above?

Comment: @martin I'm expecting increasing integers that resets every time the request is repeated.

Comment: Your question does not match your example.  You are creating a single observable chain.  Even if you put a delay in between `repeatWhen` and `subscribe` you could rest assured that the final value would be in `num_packets`.   Your question would only matter if you called `subscribe` multiple times or created multiple observable chains in some other way.

Comment: @Pace No, the `repeatWhen` notifier depends on the `BehaviorSubject` value on completion of the _original_ stream, so a delay between `repeatWhen` and `subscribe` would lead to a fundamentally different stream than synchronous propagation.

Comment: You are correct, I tested it out.  The complete signal cuts off anything in the delay queue.